# How to remove a fieldset from around a Mailchimp Subscription field?

Tags: emails, forms

I have added a Mailchimp Subscription field to an entity form using the [Mailchimp](https://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module. I'm having difficulty in removing the fieldset around this subscription field.

I have installed the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module and used the `dpm` function to display info on the form. But I can't seem to find what theme function I need to override to remove the fieldset.

I have an existing form alter applied to this form, what would I need to add to my existing form alter to remove the fieldset around the field?

Comment: have you tried using css?

Comment: I can remove it with CSS but would prefer to do it through the theme layer if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use YOURTHEME_form_alter of YOURMODULE_form_alter https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

there you can alter that form. dpm or print_r $form and see where that fieldset is defined and you can unset it

you will see something like

```
array( 
   'some_field' = array(
    '#title' = 'some title',
    '#type' = 'fieldset',
  )
)
```

then you can do

```
unset($form['some_field']['#type'])
```

that should do the job